# enter key do something javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and jQuery. When I enter something into the tracking field then hit the enter key nothing happens. Because I am not using from attribute. But if I write something then I press the Check button it loads a modal and executes checkform() function. 
Question: I want to do the same thing when I press the button. How can I do this?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Tracking Kod" name="tracking"  id="tracking" 
       class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="checkbutton" 
        onclick="checkform();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Check
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkform()
{
    var tracking = document.getElementById("tracking");
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    if(tracking.value == '')
    {
        modal.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Xahiş edirik tracking daxil edin!</div>';
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        modal.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span> Gözləyin</div>';
    }
    var url = 'track.php?tracking=' + tracking.value + '';
    $.get(url, function(response) { 
        $( "#modal" ).hide(0.1);
        $( "#modal" ).show( "slow" );
        modal.innerHTML = response;
    });
}
```

I tried this code. Added to the end of the body tag:

```
<script>
$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {fnc.call(this, ev);}
        })
    })
}

$("#tracking").enterKey(function () {checkform();});
</script>
```

Comment: What happens right now? The enter key function doesn't fire?

Comment: Look to this link please: http://www.alapar.az/track/
enter this text to the field: EE040788419AE

Comment: you should use onsubmit for the form not onclick of the button, hitting enter in a text field is not going to trigger a click for a button

Comment: @PatrickEvans i know it, but when i do this method page refreshes. Now look to this link http://www.alapar.az/track/ 
I done form method. But now modal is not loading

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc) {return this.each(function () {$(this).keypress(function (ev) {
var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
if (keycode == '13') {document.getElementById("checkbutton").click();}})})
}
$("#tracking").enterKey(function () {checkform();});

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use the onsubmit event of the form and not onclick of the button, then you need to prevent the default action of the form within the callback function.

html

```
<form onsumbit="checkfrom(event)">

</form>
```

JS

```
function checkform(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //rest of code
}
```